# Got weird message and lost 5 reputation; what does it mean?

Tags: support, reputation, users, lost-reputation

I got this and lost 5 reputation. What did I do ?

```
-5   today
-5   9 mins ago removed User was removed
```

Comment: Don't feel too bad - I got hit by the same user for -120 rep!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Seth indicated, when a user account is deleted, the votes they cast are removed from the system.

In this particular case, we uncovered a fairly massive ring of users who had been committing vote fraud in [iphone] and [ios] for the last two years. Most of these accounts were removed, as well as some of the plagiarized content they had been posting. Unfortunately, it looks like they had also been voting for people outside of their ring, so some people active in that area will see these votes be removed. Most of these accounts were fake, so the votes weren't legitimate to begin with.

If it makes you feel any better, I just lost 225 points from the removal of this same group.

Comment: I always chuckle when I lose rep that way :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber you are only imitating Jon Skeet :/

Answer (score 3):

That means a user that upvoted one of your questions was removed and thus the reputation that went with it was also removed.

I'm not sure this is necessarily supposed to happen though...

Comment: oh..that was disappointing...:(

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the user in question upvoted one of your questions, and then was removed - possibly by his own will or for moderation purposes.

When a user is deleted, all of his downvotes *and upvotes* go with him. **Think of it as if the user loaned you 5 rep.**

Comment: And Stack Exchange made us forcefully return it ? 
That makes SE really effective debt collectors :)

Comment: @AshRj Yep. At least they don't spam your inbox until you press a button to return it.