# How is it possible to lose 2 rep due to a deleted user?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

I noticed this entry in my reputation log for yesterday:

> [image: User was removed]

Naturally, I'm a little curious. How is it possible to lose 2 rep to a deleted user? If it were just up/downvotes, they'd have to have downvoted me at least 4 times, which seems unlikely (I don't get downvoted much); it's not due to an unaccept because my set of unaccepted questions hasn't changed; and it seems unlikely that it's a suggested edit given that I passed the 2k mark last year.

What's left to produce this rep change? (Obviously I'm not sweating the rep change, but I am quite curious).

Comment: Suggested edit most likely

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I made only 3 suggested edits before getting 2K, and all of them are still there...

Comment: It may also be that the user +1ed one answer and -1ed four.

Comment: Possible, as I said in my question, but unlikely. I think I'd have noticed if I'd been downvoted four times, unless the user did it over a long period of time.

Comment: @nneonneo You have 31k rep. Sure you'd remember downvotes =)

Comment: I do keep tabs on it >_>

Comment: the same thing happened to me

Comment: May be that user upvoted your post what you were two rep away from rep cap (i.e. 198). (20 upvotes and a downvote then that user upvoted your post which gave you 2 rep only.) **Just assuming**.

Comment: @Bart - IMO when suggested edit is removed, it don't show *user was removed*, it show us like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fSZly.png). (same like when post is removed)

Comment: Why does it feel like I'm the only user in C/C++ who isn't affected by the recent crackdown on the [ios/iphone voting ring](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176221/169611)... Almost everybody in C++ chat has had a removal event sometime in the last week.

Comment: @Mysticial Even I got hit, and I normally do C#. =D

Comment: @hims056 Is that also the case if a user was removed, taking the entire post with him?

Comment: @Bart If that was the case, then it would say "removed" with a name and link to the deleted post (for 10k).

Comment: @Mysticial Okay, good to know.

Comment: @Mysticial - You mean like [this one.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fSZly.png) Right?

Comment: @hims056 Yeah...