# User delete events are merged in the activity/reputation drop-down thingymajig

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-accounts, activity-dropdown

When multiple users get deleted, the events, and reputation changes, are merged in the activity/reputation drop-down thingymajig.

These are old pictures that I've just got around to uploading. As you can see, according to the thingymajig I lost 16 rep when a user was removed.

[image]

However, according to the reputation tab I actually lost 20 and then gained 4:

[image]

I do not think these events should be merged, in the same way that multiple answers to the same question will show up separately.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Personally, the dropdown is more of a quick summary, and in the cases like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176221/151015) where an entire ring was destroyed, it would flood the dropdown like crazy.

Comment: I'm not being funny, but does it matter whether it was 1 user or 20 users? Whichever the case, you can't do anything about it and you ain't getting that rep back :).

Comment: I like accuracy @Matt, it's not accurate. It's also slightly confusing, I started off with -20 and then the next day I had -16. It took a while for me to realise that a second user had been deleted. P.S. I really don't care about 16 rep :-).

Comment: Mmmm, I'll give you confusing; but maybe its the way the drop-down aggregates *on a whole* rather than just for removed users; I've seen the dropdown combine rep from an post which was gained over the period of several days (inconsistently), leaving me to think that I've suddenly had an influx of votes on the post, only to be disappointed to find its only because the dropdown has *suddenly* decided to aggregate them...

Comment: Yes, that's something to do with the number of days since the post last got upvoted @Matt (I think). This isn't a single post's reputation events getting aggregated though. These are two completely different users. In my case I suspect it's 4 posts (2 upvotes for mine 2 downvotes on theirs). They're completely different events... though I guess that the way the DB works might mean it's impossible to separate them out (deleted users not having _any_ posts and all).

Comment: +1 for use of thingymajig.

Comment: +1 for thingymajig (Undo beat me to it though)