# Reputation summary inconsistent in drop-down after bounty is refunded

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, bounties, activity-dropdown

A few days ago, here on meta, I offered a 200 point bounty on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/age-calculations-are-wrong-in-the-data-dump-export#comment538855_41519) question, which was recommended by Anna Lear to be re-posted instead of bounty offered, and as such, I posted a new version.

Earlier today, my reputation jumped +200 points (from 1775 to 1975), so I'd assume that the bounty was in fact refunded, but I don't see any record of it in my drop-down.

Here's a screenshot of my current reputation drop-down (it's also wrong on my [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151015/richard-j-ross-iii?tab=summary)):

[image]

And here's my reputation page:

[image]

Shouldn't we just put an entry in the user's reputation drop-down, like we currently do for deleted posts and removed users? I could see this as being quite confusing to a user who is just trying to get their question answered.

Comment: "What happens when a bounty is refunded?" You get back the reputation you placed as bounty. Your reputation history seems OK, so the problem is mainly with the reputation drop-down, right? If so, need a better title. If I was confused... need a better title either way.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I updated my post significantly, because I didn't realize that it was there on my profile page when I first posted.

Comment: Did [I give you the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178687/user-delete-events-are-merged-in-the-activity-reputation-drop-down-thingymajig) or did we just think about highlighting a similar problem at an almost identical time :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Nope, didn't notice that one.