# Show suspended users with their normal reputation in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, data-explorer, account-suspension

I was playing with the Data Explorer... And I was trying to write a query to show users who got the most % of their reputation from accepts.

So for each user: `[% from Accepts] = [Rep from Accepts] / [Reputation]`

The problem is that suspended users have a rep of 1. So they would have gained an "enormous" percent of their "***1 rep***" from accepts.

The result was that all the high-rep suspended users were at the top of the list.

---

Of course, curiosity sets in. I forked the query and tweaked it to single out these users.
And before long, I had a working query that listed suspended users in decreasing order of their normal reputation.

I took a look at some of these users and found some things that I, as a normal user, (not a moderator), ***probably should NOT be seeing***. At least not that easily...

**Examples:**

Note that some of these are on high-reputation accounts. So I'll keep them anonymous.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

In effect, I found many of the users who were involved in the [iOS voting-ring that was recently busted up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176213/got-weird-message-and-lost-5-reputation-what-does-it-mean/176221#176221).

---

**Feature Request:**

Show suspended users in the Data Explorer with their normal reputation. Don't show it as 1.

The current system of showing suspended users with a reputation of 1:

1. Skews the Data Explorer queries.
2. Makes it possible for non-moderators to obtain a list of suspended users that have reputation > 1.

Comment: Definitely agree from the perspective of not skewing metrics. Can't say I care much about the privacy of someone with 9500 points of voting fraud who is banned until 2019. Of course, there may be implications to the innocent to be considered, and there are far less grievous offenses for which a user might be suspended.

Comment: @TimMedora Those 3 examples are from 3 different users. The one with the 9.5k of vote-fraud will get off suspension 10 days from now.

Comment: I see. So the concern is that you can easily view every suspended user with a single query? or were you able to extrapolate more than that (just curious, I already +1 your suggestion on the basis of accurate results).

Comment: I think this should be classified as a feature request *and* a bug.

Comment: @TimMedora Yeah. I was able to find a large number of suspended users with a single query. (at least 100 of them) Not only that, but I did it accidentally. To make matters worse, I was able to find users who probably had a -100 red flag slapped on them.

Comment: That last image is amazing :D

Comment: "temporarily" suspended until 2026, hah

Comment: I would be in favor of removing suspended users privileges **without reducing their publicly visible reputation** because it could be humiliating to someone if their reputation is reduced to 1 and they are easily recognized as being a high-rep user. Some suspensions can be made by mistake or unfairly, and even if those things weren't true, humiliating users is not the purpose of suspending them. The public doesn't need to know that they were suspended or why they were suspended. The user just needs to learn their lesson and perhaps cool down away from the site for a while.