# A user with a lot of wrongfully awarded badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I stumbled on a user who has huge amount of badges and it looks like he doesn't meet criteria for a lot of them.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/299797/user97693321?tab=summary

He/she has

- 39 nice answer badges (and he has only one answer with 10+ votes)
- 16 favorite question badges (and he has none questions favorited by 25+)
- 7 populist badges (and none of his answers on these questions has more than 10 votes).

I didn't look through all badges. However, it looks like a lot (most?) of them are wrongfully awarded.

Comment: Are you sure the questions he answered were not deleted or his answers were deleted or disassociated with his account? Note the user has been around for a long time and more specifically during the beginning of SO when rules were different. Some of the questions he asked or answered could be off-topic now and have therefore been removed.

Comment: have you saw http://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLdT.png

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Ouch.

Comment: I just flagged this guy for mod attention. Hopefully this voting/favoriting/accepting ring will be destroyed.

Comment: I'm guessing based on that image it's already been destroyed...

Comment: @Linuxios By the look of the image posted, wasnt it already destroyed? I mean he last almost 10k rep.

Comment: -1 no freehand circles :< (kidding)

Comment: We are dealing with this user.  Bill is cleaning up sockpuppets and I have removed all of their badges.

Comment: @Linuxios How do you flag a user?

Comment: @NickCraver: Yay mods! (Thank you all for your diligence)

Comment: @Seth: You flag one of their posts with a "It needs diamond mod attention" -> "Other".

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @NickCraver I think you should add that as an answer, since it answers the question :)

Comment: @Seth I think Bill will have a more complete writeup, just doing what I can to help on the database side

Comment: Heh, this is amusing to watch; it looks like they just got a bunch of badges.  I'm guessing Nick nuked all the badges, and the system kicked in and awarded any that were still valid.

Comment: Badges? We don't need no stinkin' badges! ;)

Comment: @NickCraver Are gold/silver/bronze badge totals stored separately, or are they just cached?  (This user is now showing 3/25/53, but they only have 33 total badges.)

Comment: @bill denormalized, hang on and I'll fix with a dev route

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out in a [comment by NullPoiиteя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181352/a-user-with-a-lot-of-wrongfully-awarded-badges#comment551148_181352), this user had had a lot of votes invalidated recently.  Since badges are never removed automatically, all of those badges stayed behind as a remnant of past activities.  Since the user has already been suspended for those activities, and I don't want to flog them again for the same thing (I found no evidence of further shady voting occurring after all those votes were invalidated last time), there won't be another suspension.  I did remove all sock puppet accounts though, just to sweep up any votes that were missed before, and [Nick Craver manually removed all of the unearned badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181352/a-user-with-a-lot-of-wrongfully-awarded-badges#comment551181_181352).

Comment: There were other consequences at the time this was originally dealt with: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176221/135615

Comment: @Bill: I was looking at his (bizarrely) highest upvoted question, did some digging on the answerers, and it looks like all of the answer people are from the voting ring too. I raised some flags, but I thought I should tell you too, as you seem to be in charge of this investigation.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks.  I can't see anything that I can take action on, but we'll keep an eye on accounts associated with that user.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I just saw that they all had absurdly high upvote counts on mediocre answers and questions, and they all had huge negative reputation changes for today from "User was removed, that I assume was the same set of users that caused our prime suspect to go from 10k to 1k.

Comment: @Linuxios Ah, that must be why I can't see anything anymore.  All of the users were removed, along with their votes.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: BTW. You may be interested to look at accounts who marked his questions as favorites, because 20 favorites on 0 upvote question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643221/can-we-show-different-types-of-map-views) looks suspicious.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Here is another guy like that (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1471203/rais-alam?tab=badges). He has bunch of Necromancer, Nice Answers) which were gained and on Jan 17 he was hit with huge decrease in reputation (I assume because of similar voting ring)